# how to have buttons and social media images in salesforce email template

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-template, vf-email-template, classic

*Hi,
I have a requirement to create email template which includes company logo as header, email content , button, social media icons and other links and it has to be used in customer community.
Looks like it is easily achievable using lightning template created using content builder. But it is not supported in communities.*

*Eg:*

[image]

Hi Mr.John,

We have received your request to reset password.Please click on the button below to reset your password.

[image]

Thanks,

Service Team.

[image]
[image]

If you no longer wish to receive these messages, please click here to manage your preferences and unsubscribe.

---

*On click of these buttons, it should navigate to respective urls.
Can anyone please let me know how to achieve it using classic email templates.Which classic email template we can use - HTML(using Classic Letterhead),Cutsom (without using Classic Letterhead),Visualforce?*

Answer (score 0):

HTML email template and convert Reset Password into a button with button html code. Merge field data from Network Field will link to password reset page